# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, swift

So I changed this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width/2, 40)

}
```

to this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(collectionViewCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width/2, 40)

}
```

And for some reason it crashes.  I'm not even putting the constant to use, but it crashes which is confusing.

Full error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

My aim was to make the width of the cell the same width of the label + 5

`cell.label.frame.width + 5`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You have a bug. Something isn't working as you expect it to work. If you insist that the bug is in the code that you posted, and that the code that you posted is correct, then you'll never find out the problem in your life.

There's a crash. Rule 1: The crash is *your* fault. *Your* code is wrong. Your task is to find which code is wrong.

Rule 2: The crash doesn't care what you intended to do. You say "My aim was to make the width of the cell the same width of the label + 5". iOS is laughing about that. It told you what the problem is: You are accessing an array at index 1 when the array has only one element. It has *nothing* to do with what you think your problem is.

Rule 3: Read the error message and understand it. Forget about what you *think* should happen because it's not happening. The error message tells you the truth.

Set a breakpoint on exceptions (google for "Xcode breakpoint on exceptions", better: learn to use your tools). When it happens follow the stack trace to find the code of yours causing it.

Comment: How was this accepted as the answer? There is _nothing_ helpful in here- "If the code doesn't work, it's your fault, you figure it out." You could copy and paste this completely useless response to almost all the questions on stack overflow that have to do with crashes.  This has the same semantic value as "UR DOIN IT WRONG" and "GIT GUD"

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be that you are posting not correct cell identifier, and such cell with such index path for such identifier just do not exists, Check your cell identifier, other part of code should work fine.

Comment: I added the exact same line of code to cellForItemAtIndexPath which works completely fine

Comment: Try not using dequReusableCell function than. Collection view has its function that will return cell. It name is some how cellForItemAtIndexPath.u.

Comment: I dont understand what you're suggesting.  I've already called that function to determine what the cell will look like.  I believe I can't return the size of the cell using that function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue will happen in iOS11 series system in my case, not happen in higher version.

Clearly, it varies in different system version, when invoking `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(` in delegate `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

That is, i guess, we can not in advance use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(`, because `collectionView` instance might not have any registered cells in that time for iOS11 series.

The simpliest solution is, we should directly create a cell instance rather than using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` to calculate the size of cell.

In my case, i use

```
static func calcCellHeight(collectionView: UICollectionView, index: IndexPath, cellVm: YLMultiplePostsAboutMeCellViewModel) -> CGFloat {
        var height: CGFloat = 0

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 0)
        let cell = YLMultiplePostsAboutMeCell(frame: rect)
        cell.configCell(cellVm: cellVm)
        height = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.infinity)).height

        return height
    }
```

Hope this helps.